# Defining separate views and assets for admin interface in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to build a CMS for my site in Rails and I want to have separate styles for all the views that people reading my site will be able to see, namely `index` and `show` views, and the views that handle creating, updating and deleting views. I understand that I should probably separate these two areas out into separate controllers and namespace all the admin ones' routes, but I'm at a loss on how to do the views.

Is there any way to specify a layout, including stylesheets and javascript files, for a specific set of controllers? Note I'm using Rails 3.1 so as things are right now all my stylesheets and scripts get compiled into single files that are served with every view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was running around looking for a very similar thing.  And was lucky enough to find a great tutorial article by Iain Hecker.

[Backends in Rails 3.1](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1)

Its set up using Namespacing and Template Inheritance.  And the best part is he uses the inherited_resources gem by Jose Valim which really cleans up your controllers.

Anyway, it really got me on the right track.

Also, what will help is in your default application.js make sure to use:

```
//= require_directory .
```

instead of

```
//= require_tree
```

This will make sprockets only load files in the current directory.  Then you can add an admin/ folder with its own application.js file doing the same thing.

Then of course in you layouts/application.html.erb you use:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And in layouts/admin/application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin/application" %>
```

Hope that helps...

Adam.

Answer (score 3):

For CSS, I like to add some body classes in my `application.html.erb` that allow me to separate a) admin from non-admin, and b) the various controllers/actions from each other.  Here's what my `body` tag often looks like

```
<body class="<%= 'admin' if admin? %> <%= params[:controller].parameterize %> <%= params[:controller].parameterize %>_<%= params[:action].parameterize %>">
```

where `admin?` is an `ApplicationHelper` method defined as follows:

```
def admin?
    controller.class.name.split("::").first=="Admin"
end
```

For JS, you need to tackle view specific javascript.  For that I'm going to point you [here](http://tech.thereq.com/post/10754558724/the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-in-the-real-world-jquery).  The multiple manifest file technique discussed there could be useful for you, as you could construct an `admin.js` file that contains everything you need within your `Admin` namespace.

UPDATE: I thought this was a good question, so I wrote up a more thorough response [here](http://tech.thereq.com/post/12626477407/managing-your-admin-namespace-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting what I think you want would be to use a `<div id="index">` index stuff ....
and then use [nested layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) to style the div

Comment: Helpful, but it doesn't give me any idea of how to separate out my stylesheets and scripts.

Comment: Not clear why you think that is necessary.  If you have stylesheets for each section, just use #index, #edit etc to constrain your styles to the correct layout. Same for the js